# Soap API not working in magento 2.3.2?

Tags: magento2, soap

SOAP API not working in Magento-2.3.2. It's showing below error

> https://domain.com/soap/?wsdl&services=integrationAdminTokenServiceV1

```
env:Receiver The "decimal" class doesn't exist and the namespace must be specified. Verify and try again. <![CDATA[#0 /var/www/html/c/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php(219): Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor->register('decimal') #1 /var/www/html/c/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php(188): Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor->_processMethod(Object(Zend\Code\Reflection\MethodReflection), 'CheckoutDataShi...') #2 /var/www/html/c/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php(152): Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor->_processComplexType('\\Magento\\Checko...') #3 /var/www/html/c/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php(219): Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor->register('\\Magento\\Checko...')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try eith this url to find admin token.

```
https://domain.com/soap/store_code?wsdl&services=integrationAdminTokenServiceV1
```

Here `store_code` should be like `all`, `default`, or `your_store_code`.
Secondly, to get admin token, you need to pass `authentication` token.

Hope  it helps!!

Comment: I have check-in postman with token

Comment: try soap ui. To run soap api, soapUi is best.